# How are 3D coordinates transformed to 2D coordinates that can be displayed on the screen? What is the formula for this?

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems

The title asks it all, and could someone please also explain the formula as well? Thanks.

Comment: short answer : divide by $z$. If $x$ is horizontal, $y$ vertical and $z$ the distance orthogonal to the screen (from your eye) then coordinates will be $s\cdot \frac xz$ and $s\cdot \frac yz$ with $s$ a scaling factor proportional to (say) vertical resolution of screen. This because an object $n$ times farther will appear $n$ times smaller (or because you compute the intersection of every line from your eye to the screen plane).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection

Answer (score 3):

Projection has two components: the model and the camera. The camera has two parts, the focal point and the image plane. The model is what you're looking at. The focal point is a point, and the image plane is a plane not containing it.

To project a point onto the plane, we simply draw a line segment between it and the focal point, and record where it intersects with the image plane. To make things easy, we'll put the camera in standard position: focus is at $\langle 0, 0, 0 \rangle$, and the image plane is $z = 1$. This makes projection nearly trivial: $\langle x, y, z \rangle$ projects to $\langle \frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{z}, 1 \rangle$. This is referred to as a **perspective divide**. [I'll put up a picture in a bit]

This is only practical if your camera and image plane are in that configuration to begin with. So, typically, matrix transforms are used to move the *model*, not the camera.

Since these translations often require translation, simple $3 \times 3$ matrices won't suffice. Any such matrix will fix the origin (**linear transform**), which is not what we want (**affine transform**). Instead, we use **homogeneous coordinates**. There are four coordinates, $x$, $y$, $z$ and $w$, not all zero. We say that scalar multiples of these are equivalent, that is: $[x, y, z, w] \sim [\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z, \lambda w]$, for all $\lambda \ne 0$. This allows us to use $4 \times 4$ matrices for transformations. For example, this matrix translates by $\langle a, b, c \rangle$.

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 1 & 0 & b \\
0 & 0 & 1 & c \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{matrix}
x + a \\
y + b\\
z + c\\
1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

In general, we put any reflections or rotations in the upper left corner, and translations in the upper right. Let $T$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix representing a linear transformation, and $A$ be a $3$-vector for translation. $v$ is the vector we are transforming.

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
T & A \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
v \\
1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{matrix}
Tv + A \\
1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

It is clear, we have transformed our vector linearly, then translated it. Now, all the transformations we needed are just matrices. So we can multiply them together, and get just one $4 \times 4$ matrix. Conveniently, we can also represent perspective divides as a matrix, giving us just one matrix for projection!

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
\left[ \begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
z \\
\end{matrix} \right]
\sim
\left[ \begin{matrix}
x/z \\
y/z \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

We end up with just one matrix that transforms a point into position, then projects it onto the image plane.

Note: This part is more computer programming than math, but it's useful anyway. If $w$ is non-zero, we can divide through by it to get an equivalent set of coordinates with $w = 1$. So there are only two types of coordinates: $w = 1$ and $w = 0$. We use the former for points, because translations affect them, and the latter for vectors, because they don't. For example, try using the translation matrix above on $[x, y, z, 0]$. Is this behavior what we expect from a vector? Try a rotation matrix ($4 \times 4$) on both. Why does this affect them in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

yes, 
where x,y,z 3d coordinates with z being depth
x',y' 2d coordinates
maxx', minx', maxy', miny' are the limits of the screen
maxx and maxy are the maxium distance displayed on the screen at z=0
Cz= a constant to multiple z so infinite is at the center

x'= x/maxx * ((maxx'-minx')/(2^z*Cz)) + (maxx'- maxx/2^z*Cz)/2
y'= y/maxy * ((maxy'-miny')/(2^z*Cz)) + (maxy'-maxy'/2^z*Cz)/2

a screen 100*100 max of 10 miles Cz=1, so at an infinite point, x,y=(50,50)

Comment: Please use Tex.